# I'm trying to create a dynamic menu on a HTML web page using JavaScript, but keep having trouble

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, menu

Okay so here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Menus</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Cities.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="Countries" name="countries" onchange="populate('Countries','Cities')">
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<select id="Cities" name="cities">
    <option value="">Cities</option>
</select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Okay, so all seems good here so far and here is my JavaScript code

```
//Populates Countries and Cities select form elements

function populate(s1,s2)

{

var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);//s1==Countries

var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);//s2==Cities

s2.innerHTML="";

/**
 * if s1==Ireland print Dublin
 */
if(s1.value=="Ireland"){
    var optionArray = ["|", "dublin|Dublin"];
}
/**
 * If s1==Romania print Bucharest
 */
else if (s1.value=="Romania"){
        var optionArray=["|", "bucharest|Bucharest"];
    }

/**
 * if s1==England print Liverpool
 */
else if (s1.value=="England"){
        var optionArray=["|", "liverpool"|"Liverpool"];
    }

/**
 * if s1==Spain print Madrid
 */
else if (s1.value=="Spain") {
        var optionArray=["|", "madrid"|"Madrid"];
}

/**
 * if s1==Germany print Munich
 */
else if (s1.value=="Germany"){
    var optionArray=["|","munich"|"Munich"];
}


for(var option in optionArray){
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML=pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
}

}
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do is create if and if else statements so that if a certain select element from the html file is selected that it will print out a city from that country.

Now the weird part is that it works perfectly for Ireland and Romania and when they are selected I have the option to select Dublin or Bucharest from the other drop down menu, but it does not work for any of the other 3 countries?

Now seeing as it works for the first two select elements this makes me think that there is a problem either in my for loop or my HTML code but I'm not entirely sure. It might even just be a small problem staring me in the face that I just can't see.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "Countries1" is what? Look at your developer console, it will have that error....

Comment: Check your quotes

Comment: Whoops sorry that was a leftover bit from when I tried to fix it. But yeah that's not the problem. It's just 'Countries' now though.

Comment: Solved now guys, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Andreas mentioned the problem lies with the quotes in optionsArray assigment in the first two its correct:

`var optionArray = ["|", "dublin|Dublin"]`

After that its like this:

`var optionArray=["|", "liverpool"|"Liverpool"]`

See the extra quotes

[**Here**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/gwgzGr) is the corrected example i made for you.

Comment: Ahhhhh thank you! Don't know how I missed that. Stupid mistake really, thanks again man.

Comment: Np glad it helped.